# INSERT Statement error message references column I am not including in query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using MSSQL 2008.

My INSERT statement is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO [DB1].[dbo].[SpotArtSong](ID)
SELECT  SNG.S_ID
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[SpotArtSong] SPOT
INNER JOIN [DB2].[dbo].[nt-art] ART 
ON ART.Artist_Name LIKE SPOT.[Artist]+'%'
INNER JOIN [DB2].[dbo].[nt-sng] SNG 
ON ART.Artist_ID  = SNG.Artist_ID
AND left(SNG.SONG_TITLE,10) = left(SPOT.[Song],10)
WHERE spot.BDSID is NULL
```

Column [ID] on [DB1].[dbo].[SpotArtSong] has some null values that I am trying to replace. I have found the replacements and when looking over the full column results, I am happy with what the search would return from SNG.S_ID. I am trying to insert that one column into the one column on [DB1].[dbo].[SpotArtSong].

Essentially, I scrapped some data into [DB1].[dbo].[SpotArtSong] and I am matching it to some existing production data split among [DB2].[dbo].[nt-art] (ART) and [DB2].[dbo].[nt-sng] (SNG). I know the data in ART and SNG is correct, I am correlating it with the scrapped data in SPOT

The failure statement says:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Artist', table 
'DB1.dbo.SpotArtSong'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT 
fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I am not inserting anything there so I am not sure why it would fail. Plus, if I comment out the insert statement, the select statement does not return any NULL values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The table `SpotArtSong` which you are trying to insert some records has at least these columns:

- ID
- Artist

You are just supplying a value for ID, but column `Artist` has a `NOT NULL` constraint. When you don't supply a value for a column (by omitting it from the `INSERT` list), `NULL` is inserted by default unless there is a `DEFAULT` constraint. Because this column doesn't allow `NULL` values, the insert statement fails.

Either supply a value for the `Artist` column (and any other column that is `NOT NULL`) or change the `NOT NULL` constraint on that column.

To supply the artist name, add the `Artist` column name to the `INSERT` and supply a value through the `SELECT`, like the following:

```
INSERT INTO [DB1].[dbo].[SpotArtSong](
    ID,
    Artist)
SELECT  
    ID = SNG.S_ID,
    Artist = ART.Artist_Name
FROM 
    [DB1].[dbo].[SpotArtSong] SPOT
    INNER JOIN [DB2].[dbo].[nt-art] ART ON ART.Artist_Name LIKE SPOT.[Artist]+'%'
    INNER JOIN [DB2].[dbo].[nt-sng] SNG ON 
        ART.Artist_ID  = SNG.Artist_ID AND 
        left(SNG.SONG_TITLE,10) = left(SPOT.[Song],10)
WHERE 
    spot.BDSID is NULL
```

To change the `NOT NULL` constraint  use `ALTER TABLE` (note the lack of `NOT NULL` at the end):

```
ALTER TABLE [DB1].[dbo].[SpotArtSong] ALTER COLUMN Artist VARCHAR(100)
```

---

Althought it seems to me that you are actually trying to do an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE SPOT SET
    ID = SNG.S_ID
FROM 
    [DB1].[dbo].[SpotArtSong] SPOT
    INNER JOIN [DB2].[dbo].[nt-art] ART ON ART.Artist_Name LIKE SPOT.[Artist]+'%'
    INNER JOIN [DB2].[dbo].[nt-sng] SNG ON 
        ART.Artist_ID  = SNG.Artist_ID AND 
        left(SNG.SONG_TITLE,10) = left(SPOT.[Song],10)
WHERE 
    spot.BDSID is NULL
```

Comment: I had no idea that was even possible. To select out the data I need and say set this column equal to this other. Exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Column [ID] on [DB1].[dbo].[SpotArtSong] has some null values that I am trying to replace.

Then why are you inserting *whole new rows*?

The **insert** statement inserts new rows.

You're telling the database to create *new rows* containing only the ID values that you're going to supply.  The database is [rightly] objecting because the Artist column *must* have a value and, in the values you're supplying, there isn't one.

The **update** statement updates *existing* rows.

I think that's the one you need.

Comment: I did need an update statement, thanks for your help.